# List of two elements as tuple. Comparison with subsequent elements in the same list in a tuple

Tags: python, string, sorting

I have a list of two elements as a tuple:

```
str_tuple = [("def","abc"),("ghi","def"),("jkl","ghi"),("bat","cat"),("rat","bat"),("uuu","iii")]
```

I had tried the brute force approach to compare the first tuple's first element to the second tuple's second element and so on for finding the string match.

Basically grouping the elements till the match exists between them. When there are no matches, we keep those elements as they are.

Below is the final output expected:

```
 [("jkl","abc"),("rat","cat"),("uuu","iii")]
```

Is there any efficient approach/algorithm to achieve the same without multiple **for loops** in python. Is there any way to create any form of chaining between matched elements?

Thank you.

Comment: What about providing clear rules for the search before looking after any efficient approach/algorithm? What outcome do you expect in case of `[(a,b),(b,c),(b,d),(b,e),(c,b),(d,b)]?

Comment: You need to provide the code of your "brute force" approach in order make clear what you seek to improve.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict so that you can efficiently look up any given link in the chain:

```
str_tuple = [
    ("def", "abc"), ("ghi", "def"), ("jkl", "ghi"),
    ("bat", "cat"), ("rat", "bat"), ("uuu", "iii"),
]
graph = dict(str_tuple)

while True:
    # Combine all a->b->c chains to a->c.
    for a, b in graph.items():
        if b in graph:
            graph[a] = graph[b]  # a->b becomes a->c
            del graph[b]
            break  # restart the outer while loop
    else:
        break  # searched the entire graph, all done

print(list(graph.items()))  # [('jkl', 'abc'), ('rat', 'cat'), ('uuu', 'iii')]
```

Note that the actual output is different from your expected output, but I think that's correct since `("bat", "cat")` gets merged with `("rat", "bat")` and therefore should not be in the final result.

Note that while this code is very simple, and more efficient than repeatedly iterating over the original list to find each match, it's not strictly optimal in terms of runtime efficiency because you need to restart the iteration after each modification to the dictionary.  I'll leave that improvement as an exercise to the reader, but one approach I might suggest if you're trying to get this down to O(n) would be to maintain two different graph structures and migrate edges from one to the other as you work (so that as you restart the iteration over the original, you're not revisiting edges that you've already "exhausted" in prior iterations).

Comment: Thank you @Samwise for your answer I had updated the expected output . Are they anyway we can avoid multiple for loops. using some standard library or algorithm to achieve the same?

Comment: There is only one `for` loop in this code. What specific problem are you hoping to solve by avoiding loops?

Comment: l am curious to know if any approach exists as I see many one liner codes written using lambda expression or any other such method exists.

Comment: If you put the above code into a function, then you can call that function as a one-liner.

Comment: Could use pop(b), too.